# Erlang lists:flatten with one element

Tags: erlang

Why does erlangs lists:flatten not return a list if the nested list it takes only have one element in it.

Example:

```
DeepList = [[],[],["ONE"],[],[]].
[[],[],["ONE"],[],[]]
lists:flatten(DeepList).
"ONE"
```

This makes my following sequence difficult that contains a lists:foreach because it sees "ONE" as a list and tries to iterate over that. I'm sure I'm missing a better way of doing this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ONE" is also a list (of integers which happen correspond to printable character values in this case).

You wouldn't be surprised if you saw this:

```
1> lists:flatten([[],[],[1,2,3],[],[]]).
[1,2,3]
```

Now check this out:

```
2> lists:flatten([[],[],[79,78,69],[],[]]).
"ONE"
```

Usually it is easier (and *much* more efficient) to deal with "string" data as binaries:

```
3> lists:flatten([[],[],<<"ONE">>,[],[]]). 
[<<"ONE">>]
```

The "much more efficient" part comes from other operations you will probably be doing over the binary data (like matching, splitting, etc.) as well as the drastically reduced memory footprint of binaries.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention the power of `string:join/2` in combination with`string:tokens/2` in this case:

```
4> string:tokens(string:join([[],[],"ONE",[],[]], " "), " ").
["ONE"]
5> string:tokens(string:join([[],[],"ONE",[],"Two"], " "), " ").
["ONE","Two"]
```

But... while that is a nifty hack, it suffers from every bad aspect of being a hack (its ugly, unclear, doesn't say what you mean, is noob unfiendly, and is massively less efficient than dealing with binaries).

Comment: I definitely understand that the string is a list. I was considering flipping these to binary strings. I will give that a shot. Thank you!

Comment: Another way to do this, but leave it a string is `[lists:flatten(Stuff)]` which nests your result in a list, but that usually winds up having effects you don't intend later on down the line. Usually tagged tuples are best for data where position in sequence determines a semantic value, and I imagine you're working somewhere in that terrain (parsing user input or something?).

Comment: @RockyMountainHigh Just remembered `tokens/2` and `join/2` -- so I added an example of that combination to the answer.